# Tableview takes more time to display data when app Re-Open

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I  would like to display data which comes after calling webservice.

When I call webservice, I display SVProgress loader till response not comes.

When response comes I dismiss loader and display data in tableview. 
It works fine.  But when I reopen the app that time loader dismiss early &  tableview takes more time to display data.

I tried to reload `UITableView` on main thread after getting response but still not work.

```
let cellReuseIdentifier = "HomeTableViewCell"
  let tableViewCell = UINib(nibName: "HomeTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(tableViewCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : HomeTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! HomeTableViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        var objemail = self.arrayData.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NewHomeModel
        if objemail?.unread == 1 {
            cell.lblEmailSender.textColor = UIColor.black
            cell.lblEmailDescription.textColor = UIColor.black
        }else{
            cell.lblEmailSender.textColor = UIColor.gray
            cell.lblEmailDescription.textColor = UIColor.gray
        }
        if objemail?.fileStatus == 1 {
            cell.imgAttachment.isHidden = false
        }else{
            cell.imgAttachment.isHidden = true
        }
        cell.lblEmailSender.text = objemail?.from
        cell.lblEmailHeading.text = objemail?.subject
        cell.lblEmailDescription.text = objemail?.body
        let timestamparray = objemail?.date?.components(separatedBy: " ")
        cell.lblEmailDate.text = timestamparray![1]
        cell.btnPaid.accessibilityHint = objemail?.thread_id
        cell.btnPending.accessibilityHint = objemail?.thread_id
        cell.btnDispute.accessibilityHint = objemail?.thread_id
        var pending = objemail?.pending
        if (pending == 0) {
            self.rowIndexpath = indexPath
            cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.btnPending.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.penddingClick(_:)), for:.touchUpInside )
            cell.btnPending.add(for: .touchUpInside) {
                pending = 1
                cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.btnPending.add(for: .touchUpInside) {
                pending = 0
                cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
        }
        if objemail?.dispute == 0 {
            cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.btnDispute.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.disputeClick(_:)), for:.touchUpInside )
            cell.btnDispute.add(for: .touchUpInside) {
                objemail?.dispute = 1
                cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.btnDispute.add(for: .touchUpInside) {
                cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
        }
        if(objemail?.paid == 0)
        {
            cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.btnPaid.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.paidClick(_:)), for:.touchUpInside )
            cell.btnPaid.add(for: .touchUpInside) {
                cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            cell.btnPaid.add(for: .touchUpInside) {
                cell.btnPending.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "pending_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnPaid.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "paid_active_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
                cell.btnDispute.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "dispute_disable_icon"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    func callWSGmailMessages() -> Void {
        guard let id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "id") else { return }
        guard let email_Account_Id = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "email_account_id") else { return }
        guard let nextToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "nextToken") else { return }
        let parameters = ["app_user_id": id,"email_account_id" : email_Account_Id,"next_page_token":nextToken]
        let api =  NetworkApiManager()
        api.postReuestData(baseUrl: API.GMAIL_MESSAGES, params: parameters , result: { (result) in
            guard let dicData = (result as AnyObject) as? NSDictionary else {  return }
            guard let dict = dicData.object(forKey: "message") as? NSDictionary else { return }
            guard let dictTemp = dict.object(forKey: "profile") as? NSDictionary else {  return  }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(dictTemp.value(forKey: "name"), forKey: "UserName")
             UserDefaults.standard.set(dictTemp.value(forKey: "picture"), forKey: "profileImage")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
            guard let nextToken1 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "nextToken") else { return  }
            if nextToken1 == " "
            {
                self.arrayData .removeAllObjects()
            }
            let emailAccountId = dictTemp.object(forKey:"email_account_id")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(emailAccountId, forKey: "email_account_id")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "is_present_email_list")
            guard let arrMessages = dicData.value(forKeyPath:"message.messages") as? NSArray else{
                return
            }
            self.lblNoEmail.isHidden = true
            self.bRequest = false
            let nextToken = (dicData.value(forKeyPath:"message.nextToken") as Any) as AnyObject
            UserDefaults.standard.set(nextToken, forKey: "nextToken")
            for i in 0..<arrMessages.count{
                let dictNew = arrMessages.object(at: i) as! NSDictionary
                let objemail = NewHomeModel.init(jsonData: dictNew as! [String : Any])
                self.arrayData.add(objemail)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }, failError: { (error) in
            Singleton.sharedInstance.ShowAlert(title: API.TITLE, message: error.localizedDescription, in: self)
            return
        }, resultWithError: {(resultWithError) in
            guard let dicData = (resultWithError as AnyObject) as? NSDictionary
                else{
                    Singleton.sharedInstance.ShowAlert(title: API.TITLE, message: "Error Data", in: self)
                    return
            }
            Singleton.sharedInstance.ShowAlert(title: API.TITLE, message: dicData.value(forKeyPath: "error.message") as! String, in: self)
        })
    }
```

Comment: please add code related to what you are saying!

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Show us your code that loads the webservice, parses the response, and displays those results to the tableview.

Comment: @Rahul Fate Please post your web-service response code. So we will check and give proper responce.

Comment: I added code for related questions, i am only facing problem when i reopen app that time tableview takes time to display data and my loader dismiss early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the actual reason of this issue. When app is open that time there are two webservices called. In that case Svprogress bar is dismissed before getting data webservice which i displayed in tableview. 
I call second webservice after getting response of first webservice.

Answer (score -1):

In the 
`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, double check if you actually retrieve cells by using correct reuse identifier. 
if you create new cells regardless of how many cells the table would contain, it will cause delay and memory issue.

Comment: does your table view show any images from remote url?

Comment: yes,  in my cell having 3 buttons and i set images to that button with respective of flags i get from webservice response

Comment: check if you load images from main thread, please. i believe you of course load it from background. 
i recommend you to use SDWebImage cocoapod to load image from remote url.

Comment: ops... the code is really bad quality, and it should not be working fine. sorry, Rahul. 
i will send you an example of loading images, and texts in TableViewCell.

Here you can see a perfect example of how to use SDWebImage with TableViewCell. 
http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/display-large-collection-of-images-in-uitableview-with-sdwebimage/

Comment: images which i set to buttons are static and it is in app.  so there is no need to use SDWebImage